# Optimize cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I optimize this cypher query? It's 3-4 times slower than a similar query using Gremlin.

```
START movie=node:vertices(movieId="100") 
MATCH genera1<--movie<--()-[ratedRel:rated]->anotherMovie-->genera1 
WHERE ratedRel.stars > 3 
RETURN anotherMovie.title as title, anotherMovie.movieId as id, 
genera1.genera as genera, 
COUNT(anotherMovie) as count ORDER BY count(anotherMovie) DESC LIMIT 20;
```

I'm just trying to retrieve movies that have been rated with more than 3 stars and that have the same genera as the START node:
http://markorodriguez.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/movielens-schema.png?w=350

I'm running the query in the console and I'm using Neo4j 1.9

The Gremlin query:

```
m = [:];
x = [] as Set;
v = g.v(node_id);

v.out('hasGenera').aggregate(x).back(2).inE('rated').
filter{it.getProperty('stars') > 3}.outV.outE('rated').
filter{it.getProperty('stars') > 3}.
inV.filter{it != v}.
filter{it.out('hasGenera').toSet().equals(x)}.
groupCount(m){\"${it.id}:${it.title.replaceAll(',',' ')}\"}.iterate();

m.sort{a,b -> b.value <=> a.value}[0..24];
```

Comment: pleae paste the gremlin query, too

Comment: can you try the query with Neo4j 1.9.M02 and see if it is still slower? Is the dataset the same that Marko used in his example?

Comment: Yes, it's the same dataset and I tried with M02. It was still slower.

Comment: can you remove the distinct, you don't need it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
START movie=node:vertices(movieId="100") 
MATCH movie-->genera1<-anotherMovie<-[ratedRel:rated]-user
WHERE ratedRel.stars > 3 
RETURN anotherMovie.title as title, anotherMovie.movieId as id, genera1.genera as genera, 
COUNT(ratedRel) as cnt ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 20;
```

**update:**
based on your gremlin query, could you pls try this one?

```
START movie=node:vertices(movieId="100") 
MATCH movie-[:hasGenera]->genera1<-[:hasGenera]-anotherMovie<-[ratedRel:rated]-user
WITH anotherMovie,count(ratedRel) as allVotes, sum(ratedRel) as allStars,genera1
WHERE allStars/allVotes>3 
RETURN anotherMovie.title as title, anotherMovie.movieId as id, genera1.genera as genera, 
allStars ORDER BY allStars DESC LIMIT 20;
```

the point is to exactly define as much elements in path as possible (in this case we missed the rels names) and to omit the `user` node which i don't know how to do that in cypher but it obviously isn't listed in the gremlin code.

Comment: Yeah, it works but it's still almost 3 times slower than Gremlin. I guess Gremlin is more efficient somehow since you specify exactly what and how to do it.

Comment: this is normal in very structured queries, because in gremlin you are free to exactly describe your traverse algorithm whereas in cypher the engine tries to find the best traversal itself. i can't, however, say whether your query could be this case since i don't work with gremlin. have you maybe tried to run the cypher query several times in a row to let the cache turn completely on? and compare the best time with the best time of gremlin's caching series run...

Comment: If I run the query several times then the Gremlin query (3s) totally outperforms the Cypher query(19s)

Comment: Thanks. Got an exception after running the query like that: "Developer: Andres claims that: Aggregations should not be used like this". Btw I'm running Neo4j 1.8.1 now since that's the version available on Heroku.

Comment: there is probably something with  the `count()` and `sum()` aggregation functions used in one row. try to somehow update the query or hack that line. since i dont have your usecase i wrote the query by hard without checking it in real.